# Compare 2 sets of data and paste any missing values on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a master sheet with 1000+ rows and another sheet that "should" have the same data.  however, in reality sometimes some is missing from the master and sometimes some is missing from the query run.
for simplicity purposes let's say the unique ID is in column B.   here's my code but it's super slow and it only does a 1-way comparison.

My ideal code would be something that runs a little smoother and gives me the missing data from both the master and the query.

Is there's something wrong with the way I'm asking the question please let me know.

```
Sub FindMissing()

    Dim lastRowE As Integer
    Dim lastRowF As Integer
    Dim lastRowM As Integer
    Dim foundTrue As Boolean


    lastRowE = Sheets("Master").Cells(Sheets("Master").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowF = Sheets("Qry").Cells(Sheets("Qry").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowM = Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(Sheets("Mismatch").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row



    For i = 1 To lastRowE
        foundTrue = False
        For j = 1 To lastRowF
            If Sheets("Master").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Qry").Cells(j, 2).Value Then
                foundTrue = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not foundTrue Then
            Sheets("Master").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
            Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowM + 1)
            lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Two things that can help you speed up your code; First Add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your code somewhere and then reapply `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of the last `For` loop. Lastly, instead of using `.Copy` try extracting only the value from location to destination with `Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value`

Comment: Why are you using `Sheets("E Dump").Rows.Count` to help locate the last row on the Master worksheet?

Comment: oops, was trying to simplfy the sheet names missed that

Comment: @Maldred holy batman, application.screenupdate is freaking awesome.  sped up by a factor of 10.   I'm still having trouble with the 2nd part

Comment: Never declare anything as Integer, always as Long. Integer has a limit of 32767 and is converted to Long anyway. Declare i and j as Long, now they are undeclared, so they have Variant type by default. With huge amount of data it will influence speed, but if integers worked for this data set, there shouldn't be any noticeable improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't loop through the cells on the worksheet. Collect all of the values into variant arrays and process in-memory.

```
Option Explicit

Sub YouSuckAtVBA()

    Dim i As Long, mm As Long
    Dim valsM As Variant, valsQ As Variant, valsMM As Variant

    With Worksheets("Master")
        valsM = .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    With Worksheets("Qry")
        valsQ = .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    ReDim valsMM(1 To (UBound(valsM, 1) + UBound(valsQ, 1)), 1 To 2)
    mm = 1
    valsMM(mm, 1) = "value"
    valsMM(mm, 2) = "missing from"

    For i = LBound(valsM, 1) To UBound(valsM, 1)
        If IsError(Application.Match(valsM(i, 1), valsQ, 0)) Then
            mm = mm + 1
            valsMM(mm, 1) = valsM(i, 1)
            valsMM(mm, 2) = "qry"
        End If
    Next i

    For i = LBound(valsQ, 1) To UBound(valsQ, 1)
        If IsError(Application.Match(valsQ(i, 1), valsM, 0)) Then
            mm = mm + 1
            valsMM(mm, 1) = valsQ(i, 1)
            valsMM(mm, 2) = "master"
        End If
    Next i

    valsMM = helperResizeArray(valsMM, mm)

    With Worksheets("Mismatch")
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Resize(UBound(valsMM, 1), UBound(valsMM, 2)) = valsMM
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function helperResizeArray(vals As Variant, x As Long)
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long

    ReDim arr(1 To x, 1 To 2)

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        arr(i, 1) = vals(i, 1)
        arr(i, 2) = vals(i, 2)
    Next i

    helperResizeArray = arr
End Function
```

You cannot resize the first rank of a 2D array so I've added a helper function that will resize the results before putting them back into the Mismatch worksheet.

Comment: Jeepers Creepers. This is amazing also a little depressing.  I'm supposed to be the guru here at work and everytime i come on this site i feel like a guppy.   thanks a lot Jeeped.   

Another unrelated question, how do you guys develope your skills?  i've basically maxed out on the VBA courses and they don't touch anything even close to this.  any recommendations for someone that want to learn more?

Comment: Well, you could spend several thousand hours in the SO [tag:excel-vba] forum. The reputation that [tag:vba] has for being slow is largely due to most people writing inefficient code.