# Expanding on a written VBA script for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In my quest to improve the quality of life at work, I've searched for an answer and wound up [borrowing this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292528/compare-2-sets-of-data-and-paste-any-missing-values-on-another-sheet) (posted my current attempt at bottom of the post) to extract differences between two worksheets. While it returns the basic information, it is less QoL change than my current method, which, while it works most of the time, still fails. The current method is as follows:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(New!$H:$H, Old!$H2, New!$C:$C, Old!$C2,New!$B:$B, Old!$B2)<1, Old!$H2, "")
```

This code spans across several columns to populate the appropriate information (appointment time, date, patient name, patient ID, notes, etc). This goes on a sheet called "Removed", and I have one for "Added" where `New` and `Old` are reversed.

I attempted to modify the borrowed code to paste entire rows instead of just one column, but I seem to be failing at every turn, mainly because I am new to VBA and do not have a full grasp of it yet. Changing the first `For` loop to:

```
    For i = LBound(valsM, 1) To UBound(valsM, 1)
        If IsError(Application.Match(valsM(i, 1), valsQ, 0)) Then
            mm = mm + 1
            Worksheets("Old").Cells(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:= Worksheets("New").Cells(mm, 1)
        End If
    Next i
```

is obviously the incorrect way, and I suspect it's due to the whole thing being based on arrays. What must I change in the script to accommodate 16 columns of information that must be moved over to appropriate pages? Bonus would be putting them all on one page and appending a 17th column `Q` that indicates `removed` or `added`. Appreciate the help.

```
Sub YouSuckAtVBA()

    Dim i As Long, mm As Long
    Dim valsM As Variant, valsQ As Variant, valsMM As Variant

    With Worksheets("New")
        valsM = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    With Worksheets("Old")
        valsQ = .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    ReDim valsMM(1 To (UBound(valsM, 1) + UBound(valsQ, 1)), 1 To 2)
    mm = 1
    valsMM(mm, 1) = "value"
    valsMM(mm, 2) = "missing from"

    For i = LBound(valsM, 1) To UBound(valsM, 1)
        If IsError(Application.Match(valsM(i, 1), valsQ, 0)) Then
            mm = mm + 1
            Worksheets("Old").Cells(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("New").Cells(mm, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = LBound(valsQ, 1) To UBound(valsQ, 1)
        If IsError(Application.Match(valsQ(i, 1), valsM, 0)) Then
            mm = mm + 1
Worksheets("New").Cells(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Old").Cells(mm, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    valsMM = helperResizeArray(valsMM, mm)

    With Worksheets("Test")
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Resize(UBound(valsMM, 1), UBound(valsMM, 2)) = valsMM
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function helperResizeArray(vals As Variant, x As Long)
    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long

    ReDim arr(1 To x, 1 To 2)

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        arr(i, 1) = vals(i, 1)
        arr(i, 2) = vals(i, 2)
    Next i

    helperResizeArray = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Please, try replacing of `Cells(i)` with `Rows(i)`, or `Cells(i,1)`. `Cells(i)` should work as you need, if the sheet in discussion has data only in columns A:A...

Comment: I'll give that a try. The sheets have data from A:P, as a reference point, though.

Comment: @FaneDuru - That is one step close! I had the sheets backwards, but I'm closer to my end goal. Now I have to have it account for reschedules where the IDs in column H are present on both sheets, but the dates or times are different! Thank you! You should post this as an actual answer so I can give you proper credit!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 you can use the new `Filter`-Function

[image]

The screenshot shows the formulas using a very basic example.
"Table old" and "Table new" are created via "Insert > Table" therefore it is possible to reference the column names within the formula instead of B or D

Comment: I wish I had Office 365, but alas, I'm stuck with whatever work gives me, which is Excel 2019. I'm seeing how much VBA can expand my QoL, though, and it has helped with productivity on all ends. Just set my supervisor up with a macro to replace the 7 doctor names with their appropriate ID so she didn't have to do them manually, for instance. Thank you for this answer, because it still is very useful.